# to find the duplication of values

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a Mysql query like this SELECT *  FROM table 1  where column value = 1,2 or 3 and unique under a foreign   (under one foreign key colum value =1 should have only one entry)  find the count of duplicated values under the foreign key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT colValue, count(colValue) as cnt  
FROM table1
where colValue in (1,2,3)
group by colValue 
having cnt>1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    <Table1>.id, COUNT(<Table1>.Id) 
FROM <Table1>
INNER JOIN <Table2> ON <Table1>.Id = <Table2>.Id
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(<Table1>.Id) > 1
```

Comment: Will this find data which has more than one row? This comments sounds snarky but I am not being I am curious.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Table1 WHERE [ColumnName] = 'abc' OR [ColumnName] = 'def' OR [ColumnName] = 'ghi' HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this which gives only the unique values.

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE t
  JOIN (SELECT *,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY foreignkey_Col ORDER BY id) as rno
       FROM TABLE c
       ) ta ON ta.id = t.id
  AND ta.rno=1
```